# Link in Bootstrap popover doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, bootstrap-popover

I have a popover with focus-trigger and a link in the popover.

**Html:**

```html
<div class="tree">
    <div class="html-popup">
        Popup text <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_top">Link somewhere</a>
    </div>
    <a tabindex="0" role="button" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom">
        Text that has a popover
    </a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
$('.tree [data-toggle="popover"  ]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $(this).prev().html();
    }
});
```

Here is a live sample: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc7zn1o6/7/)

In Chrome the link opens before the popover closes but in IE and Firefox it just closes the popover.

I have to support IE9 and reasonably new versions of Firefox. How can I make the link open before the popover closes?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why do you want target `_top`. It doesn't work in Chrome neither. It works as a target `_blank`, so it is easier to apply such a target and gets the same in any browser. No?

Answer (score 9):

I guess this problem is because you use `data-trigger="focus"`. When you click link in popover, 'focus' is triggered, and then popover closed. At this time, click link event can't be excuted.
I sloved this problem by delay hide popover after click popover.

Example:
`$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({ delay: { hide: 200 } });`

Answer (score 4):

Remove Underscore from target inside  tag..It will be working fine in IE

```
    <div class="tree">
    <div class="html-popup"> Popup text <a href="http://www.google.com"   target="top">Link somewhere</a>
    </div>
<a tabindex="0" role="button" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom">
Text that has a popover</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Lanayx Check the solution simply replace _top with top as above

Comment: CHECK OUT THIS FIDDLE

Comment: Aditya not sure if there has been a BS change but this does not work (exactly my problem). The link is there but clicking on it does nothing - ie you do not go to Google.com

Answer (score 3):

I've played a bit with the bootstrap tooltip and one quick and dirty solution would be to remove the close on blur functionality and close it when any element is clicked outside the tooltip.

Here's a quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/b8hjg5x9/ .

```
$('.tree [data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $(".html-popup").html();
    }
}).on('show.bs.popover', function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
});

$('html').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover') { 
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this code only in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

If so, this is happening because this kind of virtual ambient works using iframe, which most browsers doesn't allow redirect for security reasons. Removing the 'target' attribute you'll get the following console error:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.com.br/ does not
> permit cross-origin framing.

If you are working inside a iframe a good option is change to `target="_blank"` otherwise it should work.

Comment: I updated the Fiddle to use _blank and now IE and Firefox seems to be working. We have implemented this in a customer project, but could you verify before I mark your comment as an answer that will this fix only work in jsfiddle or everwhere?

Comment: I did a simple html file with your jsfiddle code and works normally in FF and IE, but I tested only in last versions. Here's the code I tested http://pastebin.com/G5vaYHiA

Comment: Changing _top to _blank fixes things for IE11, IE10 and FF35 but unfortunately not for IE9. Do you know a workaround for that?

Comment: In compatibility mode works normal, i only had to allow popups.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't add a comment to your answer matheusrufca, but this doesn't help with IE9 and lower. The popover just dissappears no matter is it of the same origin or not.

Comment: The question says that only works on Chrome. I tested the code outside jsfiddle and it works. In IE compatibility mode it works well too. It's very strange a simple link inside a div doesn't open, maybe could be a preventDefault function.

Comment: I've just tried IE9 emulation and it doesn't work there. In IE10 mode link works fine. As soon as I have to support IE9 like MathiasR has, I voted this question.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onclick` to the link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/');\"> link </a>
```

worked for me. But it doesn't trigger with enter key.

Answer (score -1):

Use `_blank` instead of `_top` in anchor's target.
Then your code should look like:

```
    <div class="tree">
       <div class="html-popup">
          Popup text <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link somewhere</a>
      </div>
      <a tabindex="0" role="button" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom">
         Text that has a popover
      </a>
   </div>
```